# Microsoft.xrm.Sdk referenced in .Net core and .Net standards

Tags: .net-core, dynamics-crm, .net-standard-2.0, xrmtoolbox

My project is completely designed with. NetCore 2.2 and. Netstandards2.0. I need to refer 
Microsoft.Xrm.SDK. But Microsoft.Xrm.SDK supported by full framework. I have tried to. NetCore 3.1 also no luck. I have gone through many articles, every one saying now only they start releasing the alpha version. There is only a roadmap so far.

Comment: you have to stay at full .net framework until a compatible version is released

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already found, the .NET Core version is in Alpha release.

This is an update article to the right packages to use:

https://colinvermander.com/2020/02/13/net-core-cds-sdk-alpha-availability/

Regarding your project, you can eventually include all the calls to Dynamics 365 to a separate project/assembly so the rest of the project can be compatible with .NET Core and only that specific project/assembly to the full .NET